# Documentation for specific entity attribute's data size limits of Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016

Tags: annotations, dynamics-crm, maxlength, limits, character-limit

I have been recently working on creating **Annotations**(Notes/Attachments) on MS Dynamics CRM 2016 and ended up with different error messages from CRM Service while trying to create **Notes** with **more number of characters**.

I have searched online for solutions and only managed to found [some discussion](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/89030ea0-f81a-4d74-8cf1-91ec0bf15df1/crm-2011-notes-annotation-entity-character-limit-or-maximum?forum=crm) specifying the character limit(**100000**) for a Note and also I have learned that these limits are restricted by the "**MaxSupportedLength**" property of the metadata for various attribute types as in Annotation entity's "**notetext**" attribute is of type "**Memo**" which is having **MaxSupportedLength** of **1048576** but the specific length limit for **notetext** is different from this. The same is the case with "**subject**" attribute as well.

Could anyone please direct me to the official documentation for specific attribute(e.g. notetext, subject) data size limits rather than general limits or following a trail and error method through CRM API.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334398.aspx may be of interest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need documentation, you can see the actual field sizes within CRM itself and that's the only thing that matters (even if some documentation says the length is different).

1. Go to `Settings` > `Customization` and click `Customize the system`.
2. From the list of entities expand the `Annotation` entity and then click `Fields`.
3. Double click the `notetext` field and notice its max length is 100000.
4. Double click the `subject` and notice its max length is 500.